Creating a combined query of Bugs opened in the past three months on Azure DevOps
Right now, my team lead is asking to figure out how to get a chart of the Bug work items opened in ADO over the past three months, separated into one of three categories: one for items created less than thirty days ago, one for items created between thirty and sixty days ago, and one for items created between ninety and sixty days ago. This chart was given as an example:

I've been able to create three separate queries under Boards -> Queries to create charts for items created 30/60/90 days ago, using this format:



I've looked it over and far as I can tell there's no way to combine these three queries into one in a way that can be graphed as three separate columns for each age category. I have a feeling this is something that's going to need to be charted manually outside of ADO's built-in tools, but does anyone know if there's something else I might have missed that could help?

Currently, Azure DevOps doesn't support combining multiple queries into one and showing in one chart. As a workaround, you can use Dashboard and add three charts to it. For example,

Use widget Chart for work items and configure it as shown below:

By the way, you may need to modify your query to get the correct result. Group state clauses, otherwise your query will return other types of work items whose state is Deferred.

If you want such feature in query, you can submit a feature request on Developer Community.
